# What queryset expression produces "where x != 123" for nullable field?

Tags: django

I have a nullable field:

```
class Test(models.Model):
    x = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I want to find all instances where x != 123.

```
print(Test.objects.filter(x__isnull=False).exclude(x=123).query)
SELECT [...] from testdb_test WHERE (x IS NOT NULL AND NOT (x = 123 AND x IS NOT NULL))
```

But for obscure reasons I need the query to produce precisely `WHERE x != 123`.  I know that the two are equivalent in terms of which records are selected.

I'd rather not use [extra()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#extra) because the docs state that it will be deprecated in the future.  Is there any other way to get `WHERE x != 123`?

Comment: Can't you just remove the first `filter` expression?

Comment: No.  That would return the wrong results (records where x is null).  And in any case, removing the first filter would result in `NOT (x = 123 AND x IS NOT NULL))`, which is not the same as `WHERE x != 123`.

Comment: At mysql level both `!=` and `NOT()` represents the same, can you give me the usecase why you need to implement exactly `!=`

Comment: Are you saying you want to exclude null entries as well as where x is 123?

Comment: @NiranjRajasekaran The PostgreSQL query planner doesn't treat logically equivalent expressions in the same way.  It returns the right records, but it uses different indexes.

Comment: @Sayse No, I am saying that I want a query that generates the following SQL: `WHERE x != 123`.  This has the effect of excluding null entries, but also has other effects that I am after.

Comment: Surely the output sql doesn't matter provided the results are correct? solarissmoke's comment would produce that.

Comment: @Sayse The output SQL does matter in this case.  The PostgreSQL query planner uses different indexes for different logically equivalent expressions.

Comment: Indexes in database are set at column level and its purpose is mainly to improve query performance... So it treats as logically equivalent expression (both `NOT ()` and `!=` are treated as same)

Comment: @NiranjRajasekaran  That is how databases *should* work, but in practice PostgreSQL treats `(x IS NOT NULL AND NOT (x = 123 AND x IS NOT NULL))` differently from `x != 123`.